# pandas DataFrame filter by rows and columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a python pandas DataFrame that looks like this:

```
                   A      B      C    ...     ZZ
2008-01-01 00    NaN    NaN    NaN    ...      1
2008-01-02 00    NaN    NaN    NaN    ...    NaN
2008-01-03 00    NaN    NaN      1    ...    NaN
...              ...    ...    ...    ...    ...
2012-12-31 00    NaN      1    NaN    ...    NaN
```

and I can't figure out how to get a subset of the DataFrame where there is one or more '1' in it, so that the final df should be something like this:

```
                   B      C    ...     ZZ
2008-01-01 00    NaN    NaN    ...      1
2008-01-03 00    NaN      1    ...    NaN
...              ...    ...    ...    ...
2012-12-31 00    1      NaN    ...    NaN
```

This is, removing all rows and columns that do not have a 1 in it.

I try this which seems to remove the rows with no 1:

```
df_filtered = df[df.sum(1)>0]
```

And the try to remove columns with:

```
df_filtered = df_filtered[df.sum(0)>0]
```

but get this error after the second line:

```
IndexingError('Unalignable boolean Series key provided')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do it with `loc`:

```
In [90]: df
Out[90]:
    0   1   2   3   4   5
0   1 NaN NaN   1   1 NaN
1 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   1   1 NaN NaN   1 NaN
3   1 NaN   1   1 NaN NaN
4 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN

In [91]: df.loc[df.sum(1) > 0, df.sum(0) > 0]
Out[91]:
   0   1   2   3   4
0  1 NaN NaN   1   1
2  1   1 NaN NaN   1
3  1 NaN   1   1 NaN
```

Here's why you get that error:

Let's say I have the following frame, `df`, (similar to yours):

```
In [112]: df
Out[112]:
    a   b   c   d   e
0   0   1   1 NaN   1
1 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   0   0   0 NaN   0
3   0   0   1 NaN   1
4   1   1   1 NaN   1
5   0   0   0 NaN   0
6   1   0   1 NaN   0
```

When I sum along the rows and threshold at 0, I get:

```
In [113]: row_sum = df.sum()

In [114]: row_sum > 0
Out[114]:
a     True
b     True
c     True
d    False
e     True
dtype: bool
```

Since the `index` of `row_sum` is the `columns` of `df`, it doesn't make sense in this case to try to use the values of `row_sum > 0` to fancy-index into the rows of `df`, since their *row indices are not aligned* and they cannot be aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to remove all `NaN` rows or columns you can use `.any()` too.

```
In [1680]: df
Out[1680]:
     0    1    2    3    4   5
0  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0 NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN
2  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0 NaN
3  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN

In [1681]: df.loc[df.any(axis=1), df.any(axis=0)]
Out[1681]:
     0    1    2    3    4
0  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0
2  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0
3  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN
```